# How does the toString method work?

Tags: java

//I have been trying to understand the to string how it works and what is its main function, but I am having trouble. Like in the following examaple. What exactly does the toString method do?

```
public class Item {

    private String name;
    private int price;
    private int qty;

    public Item() {

    }

    public Item(String n, int p, int q){
        this.name=n;
        this.price=p;
        this.qty=q;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name +": $" + price+":" + qty;
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The purpose to [**toString**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) is clearly documented in the API:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.

```
Object#toString() will produce:
```

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of
>   the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign
>   character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash
>   code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal
>   to the value of:

```
 getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

If you override toString in your class call to default Object#toString() will be replaced by yourclass#toString().In your current code If you try to print Item instance the output will be of format:

```
name +": $" + price+":" + qty;
```

Comment: To add onto this: It should be said that a `toString` could be used to fully replicate the object. For example, `Tile(int x, int y, int z)` would print out like: `Tile[x=5][y=1][z=7]`.

Answer (score 1):

`toString` is typically a user-friendly/readable String representation of the object.  You can use it for debugging, logging, or to display information to the end-user/client.

Here is a short [tutorial](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=55) discussing how and when to use toString.

Answer (score 0):

The toString is the function called whenever java needs the string representation of an object of your class. For instance if you call `System.out.println(a);` where a is of type`Item`, the value returned by `toString` will be displayed. This method is part of `Object` and so every java object has some default implementation of it. Still in many cases it is not informative enough and its better to override it.

Answer (score 0):

`toString` provides a `String` representation of an `Object`

```
public class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
         this.firstName = firstName;
         this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
    }
}
```

Imagine this class and the following calls:

```
System.out.println(aPerson.getName());
```

Our `toString` methods means we can simply do:

```
System.out.println(aPerson);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to think of `toString()` as a convenience function.  Whenever you do something like:

```
MyObject m = ...//
System.err.println(m);
```

`println(m)` is actually calling `m.toString()` to get a human-readable representation of the object.  It is inherent to every `Object`, so you can always override it to have it return a String that best describes your own Objects.